# How to create a simple login system in PHP: my SQL insert statement doesn't work

Tags: php

How to create a simple login system in PHP: my SQL insert statement doesn't work.

```
<?php

    if($_POST['submit'])
        {

            if(!$_POST['email']) $error.= "<br /> Please Enter your email address";
            else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'] , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.= "<br /> Please enter a valid email address";

            if(!$_POST['password']) $error.= "<br />Please enter your password" ;
            else 
                {
                    if(strlen($_POST['password'])<8) $error.= "<br />Please enter a password with at least 8 characters";
                    if(!preg_match('`[A-Z]`' , $_POST['password'])) $error.= "<br />Please enter a password with at least one capital character";
                }
            if($error) echo"There were error(s) in your sign up details: ".$error;

            else
                {
                    $link = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
                    if(mysqli_connect_error())
                        {
                            die("Could not connect to database");
                        }   
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."' ";

                    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

                    $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                    if($results) echo "This email is already registered. Do you want to sign in ?";

                    else
                        {

                            $query = "INSERT INTO users (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']).", ".md5(md5($_POST['email'])).$_POST['password']."') ";
                            mysqli_query($link, $query);
                            echo"Registered";
                        }
                }
        }

?>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: What error does it even spit out?

Answer (score 2):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
```

You should insert, in each parameter, respectively: the host where is located your db, the username to access, the password and the name of your db.

For example

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_username", "my_password", "name_of_my_db");
```

for more information you can consult this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Likely there's another problem in this row:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO users (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']).", ".md5(md5($_POST['email'])).$_POST['password']."') ";
```

this will produce only one field containing the string "email,password", likely what is assumed that you want is that the *email* field contains the *email* value and the *password* field as well.
So, close and open again the single quotation when you want to separate the fields.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO users (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."',' ".md5(md5($_POST['email'])).$_POST['password']."') ";
```